# Armature Vertex Groups Control

Tags: python, armature, weight-painting, shape-keys, vertex-groups

**How does the Blender User get an parent armature to bind in**

**[one axis orthogonal view stripes]**

**rather than following edge loops? ... or the same effect.**

- Question is now old.  You may disregard.  Candidate for deletion.
- One immediate goal is to minimize manual weight painting.
- A related goal may be for this weight to be dynamic
- These examples are atypical, geometric, inorganic examples of using armatures and other options are being considered.  In these examples we are seeking very geometric weights.  Painting tools are not discussed here.
- In this question the number of vertex groups should match the number of deforming bones
- I would like to use existing modifiers or addons available if possible
- I may not see any proposed answer for 24 or more hours.

Thanks.

---

[image]

- A simple axis aligned mesh with weights in simple stripes.  A evenly spaced Y axis linear edge sequence was bound to an armature.  Next it was extruded in two orthogonal directions. No manual weight painting.
- The circular ring mesh would be more difficult to achieve the goal.

---

[image]

- Mesh Deform can work with the technique above

---

[image]

- This is an example of desired [stripe]. Done through modifiers.  The stripe exists or is red in a small portion near the bone.  Face connectivity is [not] considered.
- The armature bones are positioned parallel to global Y axis.  I would like to see only Y coordinate considered.
- Single example because of lack of time

---

**Python Script Success Results**

[image]

- Stripe in XY Plane or ||. Python.
- Because there is little edge alignment with X or Y axis. We think this is more difficult to manually weight paint when a large, inconvenient number of weight stripes are needed.
- The large stripe is for easy visibility. Color gradient along Y axis.   Concrete Python improvements are possible.
- Read Python at your own risk.  Python subject to massive cleansing and refactoring.  Minimally tested. Please inspect and improve.

[image]

- A comparison of Armature Placement and Mesh Modifier.  They are similar for this simple test.  Testing remains. Arrow indicates only the Armature Modifier is active.

---

Failures and Less Desirable Experiments Follow.

---

[image]

- Failure.  Top Half image. Automatic Armature weights. Weight stripes with weights fail to meet current needs.
- Bottom Half image. Weights manually modified to have identical weights for vertex with same Y coordinate.  Results work. Excessive manual labor.
- The mesh structure makes it easy for this example. Easy to weight paint probably.  Guides are built in.

---

[image]

- Failure. Automatic weights by edit mode scaling by .01 in X direction.  Armature Binding again.  Edit mode restore original scale. Undesirable weights visible.

---

[image]

- Ordinary armature binding
- Failure for atypical use of Armature.
- The vertex group follows an edge loop.  This is [contrary] to my requirement in this example.
- The vertex group for Bone.001 is shown.  Red indicates location and bone names are visible.

---

[image]

- Failure. An attempt to use a Shape Key to flatten the mesh and then bind again to the armature.  This effort has failed so far.  I will attempt again.
- Duplicating Mesh with Armature.

  - Specifying duplicate with flat mesh only [shape key] and applying armature
  - Adding Shape Key from original.
  - Fails with my sequence of steps perhaps because of binding recognizing face connectivity
- So this prompts one to think about whether or not Blender can bind to a Shape Key.

---

[image]

- Failure. Experiment. Faces are separate. See Gaps. Bone effects seems more localized. This is not a solution to the requirements.

---